# ¿Como posicionar mi label a la altura del input bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con `bootstrap` y he creado un formulario dentro de un modal y el problema es que los `label` no estan a la altura de los `input`  si no un poco más arriba quisiera saber como poder ubicarlos a la misma medida.

Por ejemplo el label se encuentra al costado del input pero no están a la misma altura, si no que el label esta más arriba, y además de ello que estructura seguir para manejar el sistemas de grillas de bootstrap.

```js
$ (document).ready (function () {
  MetodosJob.botonNuevo ();
});

var MetodosJob = function () {
  return {
    botonNuevo: function () {
      $ ('#btnNuevoJob').click (function () {
        $ ('#exampleModal').modal ('show');
    });
    }
   };
  }();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="btnNuevoJob">
            Nuevo Tarea
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nueva Tarea Programada</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idNombre">Nombre:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNombre">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnJobsSchedule" disabled>Trabajo en
                                            Horario</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idTipoHorario">Tipo Horario:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select id="idTipoHorario" class="form-control"
                                            onchange="MetodosJob.habilitarRecurrenteUnaVez(this.value)">
                                            <option value="1">Recurrente</option>
                                            <option value="2">Una Vez</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="chkEnabled">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="chkEnabled">
                                            Habilitado
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <legend>Una vez Ocurre</legend>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idFecha">Fecha:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="idFecha">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idHora">Tiempo:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="idHora">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <legend>Frecuencia</legend>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idOcurre">Ocurre:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <select id="idOcurre" class="form-control"
                                            onchange="MetodosJob.frecuenciaDiaSemMes(this.value);">
                                            <option value="1">Diario</option>
                                            <option value="2">Semanal</option>
                                            <option value="3">Mensual</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row frecuenciaDia">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idRepite">Se repite cada:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idRepite">
                                    </div>
                                    dia(s)
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row frecuenciaSemana">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idRepiteSem">Se repite cada:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idRepiteSem">
                                    </div>
                                    Semana(s) el
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row frecuenciaMes">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio"
                                                name="blankRadio" id="FrecRadio1" value="1">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="FrecRadio1">
                                                    Día
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="frecMensNum">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <span>de cada</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nroMeses">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <span>mes(es)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row frecuenciaMes">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio"
                                                name="blankRadio" id="FrecRadio2" value="2">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="FrecRadio2">
                                                    el
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <select id="Orden" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="1">Primero</option>
                                            <option value="2">Segundo</option>
                                            <option value="3">Tercero</option>
                                            <option value="4">Cuarto</option>
                                            <option value="5">Último</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <select id="OrdenSemana" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="1">Lunes</option>
                                            <option value="2">Martes</option>
                                            <option value="3">Miercoles</option>
                                            <option value="4">Jueves</option>
                                            <option value="5">Viernes</option>
                                            <option value="6">Sabado</option>
                                            <option value="7">Domingo</option>
                                            <option value="8">Día</option>
                                            <option value="9">Día de Semana</option>
                                            <option value="10">Fin de Semana</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <span>de cada</span>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idFrecMesInput">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <span>mes(es)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox frecuenciaSemana">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkLunes" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkLunes">Lunes</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkMiercoles" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkMiercoles">Miercoles</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkViernes" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkViernes">Viernes</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSabado" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkSabado">Sabado</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkMartes" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkMartes">Martes</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkJueves" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkJueves">Jueves</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkDomingo" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkDomingo">Domingo</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <legend>Frecuencia Diaria</legend>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                                                name="blankRadioDiaria" id="FrecDiaRadio1" value="1" checked>
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="FrecDiaRadio1">Ocurre una vez en:</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="idOcurreUnaVez">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idEmpezar">Empezar en:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="idEmpezar">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                                                name="blankRadioDiaria" id="FrecDiaRadio2" value="2">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="FrecDiaRadio2">Ocurre una vez en:</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idFrecOcu">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <select id="idHoraporFrec" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">hora(s)</option>
                                            <option value="">minuto(s)</option>
                                            <option value="">segundo(s)</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idTermFrec">Termina en:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="idTermFrec">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <legend>Duración</legend>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idFechaIni">Fecha Inicio:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="idFechaIni">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radios1"
                                                name="gridRadios" value="1">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="radios1">
                                                Fecha Fin:
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radios2"
                                                name="gridRadios" value="2">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="radios2">
                                                Sin Fecha Fin:
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="idFechaFinRadio">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <legend>Resumen</legend>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <label for="idDescripcion">Descripción</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="idDescripcion" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  MetodosJob.botonNuevo();
});

var MetodosJob = function() {
  return {
    botonNuevo: function() {
      $('#btnNuevoJob').click(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      });
    }
  };
}();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="btnNuevoJob">
            Nuevo Tarea
        </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nueva Tarea Programada</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="idNombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNombre">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnJobsSchedule" disabled>Trabajo en
                                            Horario</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

Quita el div del tus label y agregar esto `<label for="xxxx" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">xxxx</label>` esto hará que tus labels se centren con los inputs al medio.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **form-inline** para centrar verticalmente la etiqueta label al lado del input como lo puedes ver en la documentación de bootstrap, aqui te dejo el enlace [documentacion bootstrap 4.4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#inline-forms)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword6">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword6" class="form-control mx-sm-3" aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline">
    <small id="passwordHelpInline" class="text-muted">
      Must be 8-20 characters long.
    </small>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]